# How Do I Get Rid Of Code Showing Up After the Paypal Express Button on the Product Page?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, product-page, code

[image]

How Do I Get Rid Of Code Showing Up After the Paypal Express Button on the Product Page?

I've attached an image of the problem.

I'm using Magento vers. 1.9.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have missed or wrong tag somewhere near this code. Just lokup for this code in all project using Shift+Ctrl+f in phpstorm and fix tag.